# Convert Sequelize model to JSON Schema for user input validation

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

Planning to use [AJV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv)
for validating user inputs. AJV needs data model JSON Schema to validate user inputs. So, we need to derive JSON Schema from Sequelize model. Is there a way to get [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) from Sequelize model programatically?

Comment: [sequelize-json-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-json-schema) shall be used to generate required JSON Schema for AJV compile. However, It has an [issue](https://github.com/chaliy/sequelize-json-schema/issues/9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A late answer, but I ended up creating [sequelize-to-json-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/sequelize-to-json-schema) to solve this for our needs.

It offers more customisation in terms of which attributes you include in your schema and adding virtual attributes that might be used by your create method or similar.

**Example**

```
// assuming you have a user model with the properties
// name (string) and status (enum: real, imagined)
const schemaFactory = require('sequelize-to-json-schema');

const factory = new SchemaFactory({
  customSchema: {
    user: { 
      name: { description: "The user's name" },
      status: { description: 'Was it all just a dream?' },
    },
  }
  hrefBase: 'http://schema.example',
});
const schemaGenerator = factory.getSchemaGenerator(User);
const schema = schemaGenerator.getSchema();

// Results in
schema = {
  {
    title: 'User',
    '$id': 'http://schema.example/user.json',
    type: 'object',
    '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#',
    properties: {
      name: {
        '$id': '/properties/fullname',
        type: 'string',
        examples: [],
        title: 'Name',
        description: "The user's name",
      },
      status: {
        '$id': '/properties/status',
        type: 'string',
        examples: ['REAL', 'IMAGINED'],
        enum: ['REAL', 'IMAGINED'],
        title: 'Status',
        description: 'Was it all just a dream?'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** `sequelize-to-json-schema` generates draft-06 schemas, to use that with AJV, their README says you'll need to do:

```
ajv.addMetaSchema(require('ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-06.json'));
```

Comment: @ChristopherJ is it possible to use sequelize-to-json-schema with sequelize v4?

Comment: We wrote it against an older version of sequelize. If there's significant changes in the API that breaks it, happy to look at a PR to make it work with v4

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJ! I got it to work, at least with the v4 feature set we're using :)

Comment: Brilliant. Would love to know the project that's using it :-)